# Writing a SQL query using SELECT JOIN SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm an SQL newbee and I'm stuck on the following problem.

I've got this table and data:

**SALES_COUNTRY**

| Date | ID_Country | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/01/01 | USA | 23 |
| 2022/01/01 | USA | 14 |
| 2022/01/01 | USA | 9 |
| 2022/01/01 | USA | 16 |
| 2022/01/01 | CAN | 15 |
| 2022/01/01 | CAN | 19 |
| 2022/01/01 | CAN | 9 |
| 2022/01/01 | CAN | 23 |
| 2022/01/01 | USA | 16 |
| 2022/01/01 | MEX | 20 |

**COUNTRY**

| ID_Country | Description |
| --- | --- |
| USA | United States |
| CAN | Canada |
| GRL | Greenland |

Now I'm trying to pull the corresponding matching data from `COUNTRY.Description` and `SALES_COUNTRY.Sales` using the `ID_Country` column, which is no problem. But I'm not able to write a query that returns the sum of all `SALES_COUNTRY.Sales` of all repeated `COUNTRY.ID_Country` columns.

The output would need to look something like this:

| Id_Country | Country | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USA | United States | 78 |
| CAN | Canada | 66 |
| MEX |  | 20 |
| GRL | Greenland |  |

This is the closest I've got, but I can't seem to get SUM working together with JOIN:

```
SELECT 
    SALES_COUNTRY.ID_Country AS 'Id_Country',
    COUNTRY.Description AS 'Country',
    SALES_COUNTRY.Sales
FROM
    SALES_COUNTRY
INNER JOIN 
    COUNTRY ON SALES_COUNTRY.ID_Country = COUNTRY.ID_Country;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What DBMS you are using? MySQL, Postgres, SQL Server ...

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply. I'm having a rainy day so I took a nap. I'm using MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `group by` + `sum` operation

```
SELECT SALES_COUNTRY.ID_Country as 'Id_Country',
COUNTRY.Description as 'Country',
SUM(SALES_COUNTRY.Sales)
FROM SALES_COUNTRY 
INNER JOIN COUNTRY ON SALES_COUNTRY.ID_Country = COUNTRY.ID_Country 
GROUP BY SALES_COUNTRY.ID_Country, COUNTRY.Description
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can clearly see what I was doing wrong. I may add that I ended up using a FULL JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN to solve my problem.